# Change â‚¬ symbol (saved in database) to € (Euro Symbol) in FPDF PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, internationalization, fpdf

I want to show euro symbol that saved in mysql database, in mysql database the symbol is saved as "â‚¬", when I show in html it was automatically show as "€", is there a way to convert "â‚¬" to "€" again.
Here is my code :

```
function GetRate($NoPo){
    global $dbname;

    $String = "SELECT ".$dbname.".ratesymbol from 
    WHERE code= '".$code."'";
    $Result = fetchData($String);
    return $Result; 
}
$DataRate = GetRate($_GET['code']);    
$pdf->MultiCell(0,4,$DataRate [0]['ratesymbol']) ',0,'L');
```

anybody can help ?

Comment: Is your database configured to hold UTF-8?

Comment: Please look at SQL Injection attacks. Your code is innately insecure as written.

Comment: Similar to what @Dragonthoughts says, get your database right first, and then you won’t have this problem.

Comment: I don't even see how that pasted function above could even work. It should be throwing fatals about fetchData not existing.

Comment: If your database is storing "â‚¬" then your database is storing garbage. "€" in the database looks like "€", not like "â‚¬". Fix your database/the way you put data into your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure your web pages are in UTF-8.

2) Make sure your database holds UTF-8.

3) Make sure your forms submit UTF-8.

4) Make sure any database updates use UTF-8.

Together these will roundtrip any characters in the Unicode code set.

Also, ALWAYS use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.